# Can I prevent breaking anti-aliasing rules using this technique?

Tags: c++

If I recall correctly, it would be undefined behavior to write to `FastKey::key` and then read from `FastKey::keyValue`:

```
struct Key {
    std::array<uint8_t, 6> MACAddress;
    uint16_t EtherType;
};

union FastKey {
    Key key;
    uint64_t keyValue;
};
```

However, I have been told that if I add char array to the union then the UB is cleared:

```
union FastKey {
    Key key;
    uint64_t keyValue;
    char fixUB[sizeof(Key)];
};
```

Is this true?

#### Edit

As usual my understanding was wrong. With the new information I gathered, I think that I can get the key as a `uint64_t` value like this:

```
struct Key {
    std::array<uint8_t, 6> MACAddress;
    uint16_t EtherType;
};

union FastKey {
    Key key;
    unsigned char data[sizeof(Key)];
};

inline uint64_t GetKeyValue(FastKey fastKey)
{
    uint64_t key = 0;
    key |= size_t(fastKey.data[0]) << 56;
    key |= size_t(fastKey.data[1]) << 48;
    key |= size_t(fastKey.data[2]) << 40;
    key |= size_t(fastKey.data[3]) << 32;
    key |= size_t(fastKey.data[4]) << 24;
    key |= size_t(fastKey.data[5]) << 16;
    key |= size_t(fastKey.data[6]) << 8;
    key |= size_t(fastKey.data[7]) << 0;
    return key;
}
```

I suspect that this will be equally fast as the original version. Feel free to correct me.

#### Update

@Steve Jessop I implemented a [quick benchmark](http://ideone.com/DlXDo) to test the performance of memcpy vs my solution. I'm not a benchmarking expert, so there may be stupid errors in the code the lead to wrong results. However, if the code is right then it would seem that memcpy is much slower.

**Note: It seems the benchmark is wrong because the time to calculate the time for fast key is always zero.** I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: It's UB either way, but `g++` allows this as long as you use the union.  It's not safe to rely on this however, as it is compiler specific.  The only safe way to do it is access it via a `char*/unsigned char*/signed char*` or their const versions, as there is an exception for strict aliasing for those types.

Comment: When you're in doubt about aliasing and the use of unions to type-pun, you can *always* remove that doubt by writing `uint64_t GetKeyValue(Key slowkey) { uint64_t key; std::memcpy(&key, &slowkey, sizeof(key)); return key; }`. It's less code, there's no particular reason to think that it will be slow, and it's correct provided that you make sure the sizes match. Which you have to do with the union anyway, to ensure you aren't including uninitilialized junk in your key.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for the suggestion. See my edit for a benchmark.

Answer (score 4):

No, reading a `uint64_t` if you have a `Key` object there is still UB. What isn't UB is to read a `char`, because there's an exception for `char` in the aliasing rules. Adding the array doesn't propagate the exception to the other types.

The version in the edit seems fine (though I'd use `unsigned char`), but now it is more complex than just using a `reinterpret_cast` from `Key*` to `unsigned char*` or a `memcpy`.

Comment: Has C++11 added the rule C99 added, that when you read a union through the "wrong" member, what you get is a reinterpretation of the object representation of the member you wrote? Without that rule, this is UB irrespective of whether the alias is legal.

Comment: It says you can access any object through a `char` reference (busy, can't look for quotes right now). It defines a notion it calls "active member", but it doesn't make any claims of reading from another member being UB. The "active member" thing is only used to explain how to change the active member, and to define constant expressions.

Comment: A reinterpret cast would be correct as well? E.g. `reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(fastKey.data)`

Comment: No, a reinterpret cast to a *char* pointer/reference. There must be `char`s involved.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: sure, I know you can access the object through `(char*)(&any_old_object)`. My doubt is whether you can use an inactive member of a union (officially you can't in C89 or in C++03). Just because it's legal to alias as `char`, doesn't mean that *all* means of getting a `char*` that you think points to your object, are correct!

Comment: @SteveJessop Grep the standard for "active member". It doesn't forbid you from reading from non-active members.